# why IconButton taking maximum size instead of its parent widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am creating custom widget where a container with border and child is IconButton,

here i want to place iconbutton inside container with fixed height and width but its taking main container's height and width

completly failing to understand how widget works with each other's size

sometime based on parent size and sometime on its child...is there any good way to understand this topic?

in my following code i want iconbutton of 40x40 in a container of 100x100,

i mean it should be clickable only 40x40

```
return  Scaffold(

      body:Center(
        child: Container(

          height: 100,
          width: 100,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
          ),

          child: SizedBox(
            height: 40,
            width: 40,
            child: IconButton(onPressed: (){},icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_basket),
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      )
    );
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter image in SizedBox is overridden by parent Container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57123235/flutter-image-in-sizedbox-is-overridden-by-parent-container)

Comment: This appears to be by design when you use `Container` and `SizedBox`. See the [documentation for `SizedBox`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SizedBox-class.html): "If given a child, this widget forces it to have a specific width and/or height. These values will be ignored if this widget's parent does not permit them. ".

Answer (score 2):

First, IconButton is a Material Design widget which follows the spec that tappable objects need to be [at least 48px on each side](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/8a83d0df7f2eab9d4fb29ca6bef4b7d20070a54e/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/icon_button.dart#L198)

So if you want to understand the constraint, you should change IconButton to another widget, like `Container`, for example:

```
return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          height: 100,
          width: 100,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
          ),
          child: Center(
            child: Container(
              height: 40,
              width: 40,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

The different here is the `Center` widget, widget in Flutter follow the rule **Constraints go down. Sizes go up. Parent sets position.**

You can understand it by this documentation: https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/layout/constraints

Answer (score 1):

You can add some padding to the Sizedbox by making it a container and then this will reduce the clickable area:

```
body: Center(
          child: Container(
            height: 100,
            width: 100,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
            ),
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              height: 40,
              width: 40,
              child: IconButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_basket),
                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ));
```